# Flash AS3 - 2D Augmented Reality - How to display image

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3

I have been stuck trying to make an image appear after detecting my custom marker. I have been using the FLARToolKit with the Earth demo it provides to play around with the AR.

I can get the FLARToolKit to display the Earth animation when it hovers over my custom marker so I know that the marker isn't the problem. I just want to know the code on how I can simply place a flat 2D image I have over the top of my marker without any animation or movement to the image itself.

Below is the code I have been using to detect my marker if that helps:

```
public function Earth() {
        addEventListener(Event.INIT, _onInit);
        init('Data/camera_para.dat', 'Data/marker163.pat');
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FLART is not standard flash/as3 api. Could you give a like to this demo?

Comment: The toolkit can be downloaded from here, it is a zip file with all the contents. https://saqoo.sh/a/en/flartoolkit/start-up-guide

Comment: Not sure If I understand your question now but... Did you try to 1. Open model/earth.blend file. 2. Delete "Earth" mesh, and leave just "Shadow" plane. 3. File>Export>Collada.dae   4. Replace the model/shadow.png file with your own image. This theoretically should  give you custom image on marker instead of example globe though I don have camera or printer connected to test it.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how to use blender. All I want was to display a 2D image on top of a marker. The rest of the code doesn't matter so long as it displays a flat image. Thank you for the help and I have tried to do this, but blender is too confusing to me to be able to mess around with those .dae files. Any other options you could give me would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This is probably the easiest solution. If you open the file with blender you should see ping ball and pink plan. Just RMB on the ball so it is highlighted and hit "delete" key on your keyboard. Then simply File>Export>Collada(.dae)

Comment: I've made these changes and still have issues. When I insert the image as the shadow with the earth above it, it changes the shadow to the image I want. But when I remove the earth, it shows just a grey square where the shadow image should be. It is really odd that it only works when the earth is above the shadow. Any ideas?

Comment: hym.., I have not idea. Try scale the earth down to 0 instead removing it (select, hit "s", hit "0", hit "enter"). If your shadow will be still broken then this is probably exporting issue. You should read Papervision doc about `.dae` files import to see if you need to check any specific options when exporting...